# CCAvenue integration with opencart

Tags: opencart, ccavenue

I am using OpenCart as an e-commerce system and integrated CCAvenue as a payment getaway. Currently my system is only using Indian Rupee. To be able to use US Dollar, I registered new multiple currency account. Now I am trying to integrate with that new account.

I entered working key and `Merchant_id` in Cc Avenue module in payment option. While beginning transaction it gives me error with no description nor error code. Also I don't know where to put `Access_code`. Please help.

[image]

Comment: In English (and all other languages as well) a new sentence starts with capital letter. Letter `i` if representing `me` is also written in capital, thus `I`. *Opencart* is a name of e-commerce platform, *open cart* is just a cart that is opened. I can see you have no problem with the `SHIFT` keyboard key since you have no problem to write *Indian Rupee*... If requesting help it is wiser to be polite and to forget about exclamation mark after *Please help*. I think you are beginning a *transaction*, not a *translation*. I believe you are able to improve your question for yourself ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I will keep in mind on-words.

Comment: Hi, I got the same error. Given the correct merchant ID and working key, but after checkout redirecting to error page using ccavaneu. Any solution?